# Is it possible to map JSON fields to differently named properties using JAGPropertyConverter?

Tags: ios, json

I'm using the excellent open source [JAGPropertyConverter](https://github.com/jagill/JAGPropertyConverter) to deserialize JSON responses into a model object.

It's not explicitly documented, but is there a way I can have a JSON field named, say, "userName" map/deserialize into a property called "name"?

It utilizes Key-Value compliant properties, so the vanilla use case would for my model to have a property called "userName" if the JSON I was deserializing had a field called "userName".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of [76829b4dca](https://github.com/jagill/JAGPropertyConverter/commit/76829b4dca216e467ca1a38bc8606c71eae747bb), the answer is no. `JAGPropertyConverter` invokes `JAGPropertyFinder` to map dictionary keys to properties, and neither class allows you to change the default mapping.

[JAGPropertyConverter.m](https://github.com/jagill/JAGPropertyConverter/blob/master/JAGPropertyConverter/JAGPropertyConverter.m#L332):

```
- (void)setPropertiesOf:(id)object fromDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary {
    JAGProperty *property;
    for (NSString *key in dictionary) {
        property = [JAGPropertyFinder propertyForName: key inClass:[object class] ];
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

[JAGPropertyFinder.m](https://github.com/jagill/JAGPropertyConverter/blob/master/JAGPropertyConverter/JAGPropertyFinder.m#L58):

```
+ (JAGProperty *)propertyForName:(NSString *)name inClass:(__unsafe_unretained Class)aClass {
    objc_property_t property = class_getProperty(aClass, [name UTF8String]);
    ...
}
```